# JavaScript double popup modal with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to use JavaScript to pop out two modal page on my hotspot login page:
e.g.

1. if the clients device IP + MAC address is present and the clients click CONNECT button Login Modal Page Should Appear.
2. if the clients Device IP + MAC address is not present and the clients click CONNECT button Error Modal Page should Appear like (please Connect From a Hotspot)

I have tried this:

```
<?php
$mac=$_POST['mac'];
$ip=$_POST['ip'];
 ?>


  <button onclick="connect()" type="button" class="btn btn-info">CONNECT</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">

       function connect()

    {

  $('#login').modal();
 }     

    </script>
```

The above code show the login modal when the CONNECT button is clicked but I want if the ip and mac address is not present when the clients click CONNECT button Error Modal Should Pop up instead of login modal.

Comment: And what's your question about this? If you want some other behaviour, what have you tried to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to echo the values from PHP to Javascript. But beware that you need to validate these values first.

Something like this should work:

```php
<?php
// get values from $_POST or default to empty string
$mac = $_POST['mac'] ?? '';
$ip  = $_POST['ip'] ?? '';
?>

<button onclick="connect()" type="button" class="btn btn-info">CONNECT</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function connect() {
    // pass values as string to javascript variables
    var mac = "<?php echo $mac; ?>";
    var ip = "<?php echo $ip; ?>";

    // mac and ip adresses provided
    if (mac && ip) {
        $("#login").modal();
    }

    // mac or ip adresses missing
    else {
        $("#error").modal();
    }
}

</script>
```

---

A few things to note:

- This is not secure as I values passed as POST can be tampered with. As a rule of thumb, do not trust anything provided by the client.
- `<?php echo ... ?>` will "print" the values in the document. If you inspect the code in the browser, you'll see something like:

  ```js
  var mac = "mac-address-passed-as-POST";
  var ip = "123.456.78.90";
  ```
- You can simplify the `echo` statements by using the shorthand syntax:

  ```js
  var mac = "<?= $mac ?>";
  var ip = "<?= $ip?>";
  ```
- To better validate the values you get in the `$_POST` variable, you could add regex checks in the PHP part. Something like:

  ```php
  <?php

  // default values
  $mac = '';
  $ip = '';

  // validate mac address
  if (isset($_POST['mac']) && preg_match('/^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$/', $_POST['mac'])) {
      $mac = $_POST['mac'];
  }

  // validate ip address
  if (isset($_POST['ip']) && preg_match('/^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/', $_POST['ip'])) {
      $ip = $_POST['ip'];
  }

  ?>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try it out now and get back later

Comment: I thought about the value validation (MAC and IP addresses) the ip address format e.g 192.168.xxx.xxx etc and the mac address format like XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX how can i add this validation?.

Comment: The validation I was mentionning was more about checking if the value exist. This is checked with the `??` operator to provide a fallback value if not set in `$_POST`. To validate that the format is correct, you could use REGEX patterns. I'll update my answer to illustrate this.

Comment: Ok, thanks in advance and one more thing, please how can i use same javascript pattern to verify and validate data before a document load (i mean before loading a page) e.g if clients call status.php and ip & mac address is not present error modal should pop up like (please connect from hotspot or this is not a hotspot) e.t.c thanks once again for your help

Comment: Javascript can only act when the page loads / is loaded. If you want to act _before_ that, you need to do it in PHP. Make a check to either display the connect button or a script that will immediately open a modal.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your contributions, i really appreciate

Comment: have tried the above code everything works fine but i got an errow like 
**Warning**: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in bla bla bla line 33 
**Warning**: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in bla bla bla line 38
i have tried to put the code but i dont get how to. what am i doing wrong please

Comment: My bad, I forgot `/` around the regular expressions. Answer updated.